# how to define the values in json schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

**I have created the jsonform using jsonschema.
But i need to define the external values in schema.
for ex :  to define the first name value externally.
I tried with $ref to define external json but still it not works.**
In my local json values are : 
    [{
    "male": "blah blah",
    "female": "woof woof"
    }]

I inject the json values in to the below schema

"value":  {   "$ref": "data3.json"}

can anyone please let me know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$var1='{
"male": "boy",
"female": "girl"
  }';

test it like this

echo $var1;

Comment: am asking to define the external values in json schema.